# Setting a basic footer to a UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

How is a basic footer set to a UITableView programmatically?

Just a centered text?

EDIT:

How can the bar color be set and the footer bar position fixed to the bottom of the screen or if the thumbs dont fill a screen, the footer isnt above the bottom of the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use UITableViewDataSource callback (just text):

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Or UITableViewDelegate (any custom view you like):

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Comment: Can the colour of the footer be set? to e.g. UIBarStyleBlack.

Comment: If you're returning the view, then you can specify any color but if you're using text, then the color is constrained to the table style

Comment: You can return the height that is equal to the screen size via -(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView*) tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath

Answer (score 10):

viewForFooterInSection sets the *section's* footer. To set the table's footer, you want to set

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = myCustomFooterView
```

where myCustomFooterView is something you setup elsewhere. You'd probably set that in viewDidLoad.

Comment: How is a customFooterView setup?